# How To Prevent Capturing Referral - Disable Referral or Hide Referral

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Is any possible way to disable referral. I mean external site or analytic should not capture a referral of my domain.

Example : My domain example.com sending a traffic to google.com but google should not know traffic is coming from example.com

This site https://nullrefer.com/ provide a feature to Hide referral by blanking the referral but how can i do same for my website.

I am using https://www.whatismyreferer.com/ for testing. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>
```

If you put above code on your page all outgoing links (user clicks) will not send referrer information

[Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-delivery)

If you want to hide/fake your GA referrer data (GA script on your site) you can use [**dr** parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dr)

Comment: Is this small code also stop referrer detecting in Google Analytic or Voluum.com ?

Comment: Can you add some explanation to that code?

Comment: Added some information, and link to documentation.  As for GA, Google will not see referrer from outgoing clicks from your page ending on other pages. If you put GA code on your site, and someone will come from another site to you with referrer set, GA will see and use it.

Comment: @Khazul is this also works for to hide or remove referrer from Iframe?

Comment: Iframes works wrongly with this - and you need to set it independently on them, as in given by you answer.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

Iframe

```
<iframe src="https://www.whatismyreferer.com/" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></iframe>
```

URL

```
<a href="http://example.com" rel="noreferrer">Example.com</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://example.com" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">ReferrerPolicy Attribute</a>
```